# IT-Hit WebDav Server Checkout and MS Office 2007

Tags: webdav

I'm evaluating the IT-Hit Webdav component. Their Delta-V server sample is my starting point. If I open a word document directly from a Sharepoint site, MS Office shows a button which enables me to check out the document if needed. While using the IT-Hit server doesn't provide this feature for MS Office. It is important for us, that our own WebDav sever created with IT-Hit provides the same features as Sharepoint does.
Am I doing something wrong, or is this just not possible?

Rgards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft SharePoint and Microsoft Office are using a bunch of proprietary SharePoint protocols for comunication, they are not using DeltaV. IT Hit WebDAV Server Engine does not implement that Microsoft protocols. Therefore you can not achieve the same functionality only implementing DeltaV or using DeltaV sample.

The only server that implements Microsoft SharePoint protocols as far as I know is Alfresco.